# RefTeX: Is it possible to use regex to search forward to find context?

Tags: cross-referencing, reftex

I am using RefTeX to create/reference labels within LaTeX documents.

When writing definitions, I usually write the "name" of whatever I'm defining as emphasised text in the beginning of the definition environment, and I usually put the label just after `\begin{definition}`. Therefore, I would like RefTeX to do a **forward** search from the label macro for the text to use as label.

I've managed to get **backward** search working by following the [RefTeX User Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/reftex.html#Options-_002d-Defining-Label-Environments)

Here is the relevant part of my **.emacs** file:

```
(setq reftex-label-alist
  '(
     ("theorem"    ?h "thm:" "~\\ref{%s}" t ("theorem" "thm.") )
     ("lemma"      ?l "lem:" "~\\ref{%s}" t ("lemma" "lem.") )
     ("corollary"  ?c "cor:" "~\\ref{%s}" t ("corollary" "cor." ))
     ("definition" ?d "def:" "~\\ref{%s}" "\\emph[[{]" ("definition" "def." ))
   )
  reftex-insert-label-flags '(t t))
```

I can find no mention of forward search in the [Documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/reftex.html#Options-_002d-Defining-Label-Environments), so I fear this is not something that is supported by default. There is the option of defining a function for the ***context-method***, but I am not familiar enough with (Emacs) Lisp to write such a function.

Any help on this matter will be much appreciated.

**As per request, here is a MWE:**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}

\begin{document}

\begin{definition}
  A \emph{thing} is something that has a lot of useful properties.
\end{definition}

\end{document}
```

I would like that when I insert a label (using RefTeX) just after `\begin{definition}`, RefTeX automatically uses the word `thing` as the label, i.e. the resulting line should read

```
\begin{definition}\label{def:thing}
```

Comment: Have you considered using `cleverref` instead? It can extract the name from the label. (I personally use a similar unreleased package, that adds the name from the label prefix, it is not as intrusive as `cleverref` might be)

Comment: @daleif I will have a look at `cleverref`. Thank you very much.

Comment: @daleif: The package is named `cleveref` .... I stumbled so many times over this typo myself.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I should have guessed. As mentioned I don't use it myself, preferring something a bit more simple.

Comment: Are you also using AUCTeX?  Can you add a MWE to your question showing the final product you're looking for?

Comment: @Arash Esbati: Yes, I am also using AUCTeX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problem

AUCTeX comes already with a style file for [`amsthm`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/auctex.git/tree/style/amsthm.el) providing completion, parsing etc.  But it is not easy to hook your requirements into that style, hence, I suggest you write a new LaTeX package `myamsthm` with the respective AUCTeX support file.

### Prerequisite

You'll need this in your `.emacs`:

```lisp
(setq TeX-parse-self t)
```

Next, you need to customize the variable `TeX-style-private` to a directory of your choice, e.g.:

```lisp
(setq TeX-style-private "~/.emacs.d/mystyles")
```

I prefer to have something like this

```lisp
(setq reftex-insert-label-flags '("shlcd" "sft"))
```

in my `.emacs` instead of

```lisp
(setq reftex-insert-label-flags '(t t)
```

but that is your choice.

A wrapper package `myamsthm.sty` can look like this:

```
\ProvidesPackage{myamsthm}[2017/09/08]
\RequirePackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
% etc.
\newcommand\envcontext{}
\let\envcontext\emph
```

Save this file somewhere LaTeX finds it.  I suggest you use a macro like `\envcontext` instead of plain `\emph`.

### myamsthm.el

Save the following code as `myamsthm.el` in the directory mentioned above and restart Emacs.

```lisp
(defun LaTeX-myamsthm-env-label (environment)
  "Insert ENVIRONMENT, an optional argument, a reference and label."
  (let ((opthead (TeX-read-string
                  (TeX-argument-prompt t nil "Heading"))))
    (LaTeX-insert-environment environment
                              (when (and opthead
                                         (not (string= opthead "")))
                                (format "[%s]" opthead))))
  (let ((envcontext (TeX-read-string
                     (TeX-argument-prompt nil nil "Environment context"))))
    (unless (zerop (length envcontext))
      (indent-according-to-mode)
      (save-excursion
        (insert TeX-esc "envcontext" TeX-grop envcontext TeX-grcl))))
  (when (LaTeX-label environment 'environment)
    (LaTeX-newline)
    (indent-according-to-mode)))

(defun LaTeX-myamsthm-reftex-label (_environment)
  "Search for context of environment and pass it to RefTeX.
ENVIRONMENT is ignored."
  (if (save-excursion
        (re-search-forward
         "\\\\envcontext{\\([^}]+\\)}"
         (save-excursion
           (re-search-forward
            (concat "\\\\end{" (LaTeX-current-environment))))
         t))
      (match-string-no-properties 1)
    (error "Could not find the \"\\envcontext\" macro")))

(TeX-add-style-hook
 "myamsthm"
 (lambda ()

   (TeX-run-style-hooks "amsthm")

   (dolist (env '(("theorem" . "thm:")
                  ("lemma"   . "lem:")
                  ("corollary"  . "cor:")
                  ("definition" . "def:")))
     (LaTeX-add-environments `(,(car env) LaTeX-myamsthm-env-label))
     (add-to-list 'LaTeX-label-alist env))

   ;; Reftex support: Use `reftex-add-label-environments'
   (when (fboundp 'reftex-add-label-environments)
     (reftex-add-label-environments
      '(("theorem"    ?h "thm:" "~\\ref{%s}" (nil . LaTeX-myamsthm-reftex-label) ("theorem" "thm."))
        ("lemma"      ?l "lem:" "~\\ref{%s}" (nil . LaTeX-myamsthm-reftex-label) ("lemma" "lem."))
        ("corollary"  ?c "cor:" "~\\ref{%s}" (nil . LaTeX-myamsthm-reftex-label) ("corollary" "cor." ))
        ("definition" ?d "def:" "~\\ref{%s}" (nil . LaTeX-myamsthm-reftex-label) ("definition" "def." )))))

   (TeX-add-symbols
    '("envcontext" t))

   ;; Fontification
   (when (and (featurep 'font-latex)
              (eq TeX-install-font-lock 'font-latex-setup))
     (font-latex-add-keywords '(("envcontext" "{"))
                              'textual)))
 LaTeX-dialect)
```

I will not describe the code above, but now, you can do <kbd>C-c C-e definition RET</kbd> and you get completion and the final code will look like this:

```
\begin{definition}
  \label{def:thing}
  A \envcontext{thing} is something that ...
\end{definition}
```

The function you were asking for is `LaTeX-myamsthm-reftex-label`.

Comment: Thank you so much! This works exactly the way I wanted; and I can imagine it must have taken quite some time to write. One question though: with the `reftex-add-label-environments` and `LaTeX-add-environments` sections in your code. Can I remove `setq reftex-label-alist` and `LaTeX-add-environments` from my `.emacs` file?

Comment: @AcId - You're welcome, glad it helps.  Indeed, you can now remove your additions from your `.emacs`.  You can now add any new definitions to `(dolist (env '(...` and `(reftex-add-label-environments '(...` in the `.el` file.  They become effective each time you load a `.tex` file with  `\usepackage{myamsthm}` in it.  Also note that I updated my answer, please use the updated code.